# UIPageViewController set limit page

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, sliding

I'm starting study swift, and use UIPageViewController to slide 3 page. I use class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class MyPageViewController: UIPageViewController, UIPageViewControllerDataSource, UIPageViewControllerDelegate {

var pages = [UIViewController]()
var pageIndicator : UIPageControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.delegate = self
    self.dataSource = self

    let page1: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page1")
    let page2: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page2")
    let page3: UIViewController! = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("page3")

    pages.append(page1)
    pages.append(page2)
    pages.append(page3)


    setViewControllers([page1], direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.Forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
}
 func viewControllerAtIndex(index: Int) -> UINavigationController! {
    return nil
}
func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let currentIndex = pages.indexOf(viewController)!
    pageIndicator.currentPage = currentIndex
    let previousIndex = abs((currentIndex - 1) % pages.count)

    return pages[previousIndex]
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let currentIndex = pages.indexOf(viewController)!
    pageIndicator.currentPage = currentIndex
    let nextIndex = abs((currentIndex + 1) % pages.count)
    return pages[nextIndex]
}

func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return pages.count
}

func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return 0
}

}
```

But sliding didn't stops on the third page, and begins again with first page.
How limit slide page forward and backward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your index calculation is wrong in the following line.
`

```
let nextIndex = abs((currentIndex + 1) % pages.count)
return pages[nextIndex]`
```

for the last view controller  currentIndex=2 ,then nextIndex=(2+1)%3=0.
So you are returning the view controller at index 0 again.

add the following line to your method `

```
if(currentIndex == (pages.count-1))
  {
        return nil;
   }
```

`Note:this is according to objective c.

Comment: Thanks! Code for next page:`  if currentIndex == (pages.count-1){
            return nil
        }`

Comment: Previous page: `  if currentIndex == 0{
            return nil
        }`

Answer (score 1):

As UIBittu already pointed out: your calculation needs a fix.

A possible (probably more readable) solution may look like this:

```
func indexOfViewController(viewController: UIViewController) -> Int {
    guard let index = pages.indexOf(viewController) else {
        return NSNotFound
    }

    return index
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    var index = indexOfViewController(viewController)

    if (index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil
    }

    index--

    return pages[index]
}

func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    var index = indexOfViewController(viewController)

    if (index == NSNotFound) || (index+1 == pages.count) {
        return nil
    }

    index++

    return pages[index]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is different solution.
You don't need to have a full set of complex code to execute what you need.
Create a ScrollView. Set its content size width as the multiple of number of pages.

Try this code. this may help You

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let screensize = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

    pagescroll.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,screensize.width, screensize.height)
    pagescroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: screensize.width*3, height: screensize.height)
    pagescroll.pagingEnabled = true

    page1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screensize.width, screensize.height)
    page2.frame = CGRectMake(screensize.width, 0, screensize.width, screensize.height)
    page3.frame = CGRectMake(screensize.width*2, 0, screensize.width, screensize.height)

    pagescroll.addSubview(page1)
    pagescroll.addSubview(page2)
    pagescroll.addSubview(page2)
    self.view.addSubview(pagescroll)


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


var pagescroll = UIScrollView()
var page1 = UIView()
var page2 = UIView()
var page3 = UIView()
```

You can also add a pagecontroller: UIPageControl according to your requirement